# Tensorflow file_io.read_file_to_string says unexpected keyword argument binary_mode

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have just started using google cloud ml engine to train my models however, I keep running into a problem when trying to load the data: My data files are in a compressed .npz(numpy archive) format.

```
pathtodata = os.path.join(FLAGS.inputdir,'input_data_1.npz')
f = file_io.read_file_to_string(pathtodata, binary_mode=True)
data1 = np.load(BytesIO(f))
```

Whenever I try to run this on my computer, it works perfectly. The data is loaded from the correct directory. However, when I tried to run a job on CloudML, it says

```
    f = file_io.read_file_to_string(pathtodata, binary_mode=True)
    TypeError: read_file_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 
    'binary_mode'
```

I've tried using

```
with file_io.FileIO(pathtodata, mode='r') as f:
    f._binary_mode = True
    data1 = np.load(f)
```

Once again, this works on my own device, but when I load it to google cloud, I get the error

```
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 35, in 
get_data
data1 = np.load(f)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 405, 
in load
fid.seek(-min(N, len(magic)), 1)  # back-up
TypeError: seek() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I've looked at all the different ways to import data to a cloudml job from a cloud storage bucket, to no avail.

And if you are wondering why, I explicitly told the FileIO object to have _binary_mode to be true, its because it would throw the error that mode wasn't 'r' 'w' 'a' 'r+'. My computer is running Tensorflow  1.2.1. The latest runtime version seemed to be Tensorflow 1.4.0. I checked the source code on github, and it looks correct to me.

Comment: Looks like TensorFlow version mismatch to me. Which runtime version did you specify when you submitted the job to Cloud ML Engine?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and for me it was a version mismatch problem as Guoqing Xu suggested. To diagnose, have this line in your script:

```
print("TensorFlow version", tf.__version__)
```

Then you can compare the local and remote version. The default version for the ML-engine I believe is 1.0.1 which is too early to include file reading to bytes.

You can change the deployment version via the YAML or JSON file that fulfills the `--config` argument to your `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training` command or you can use the `--runtime-version` flag. E.g.

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "JOB_NAME" --module-name my_module.main --runtime-version=1.13
```

List of available versions in deployment can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list